# Getting methods from web service and their parameters programmatically

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm playing around with WCF and wondering about the following. I'd like to be able to get a list of all available service methods and parameters associated with these methods.

Now, I've tried to work with the ServiceDescription namespace, but it seems flawed. For one .svc it works, for another it doesn't.

What would be an okay way to approach this? Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just download the WSDL of the webservice and parse that (it is XML, see http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) since the WSDL contains all information like interfaces/methods/parameters etc.

Some helpful resources including source code for doing what you want:

- http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/
- http://wizdl.codeplex.com/
- http://soap-sec.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That's not as straightforward as you might think. Not every .wsdl looks the same, some import other .wsdl files. Data types of method parameters aren't even specified in the .wsdl file.

Comment: I didn't say that it is straightforward... to do this sort of thing right means some hard work... it is possible... and the links I provided point to tools doing that already and come with source code... check them out...